# Exactly which parts of the selichot are in Aramaic and to be skipped when davening without a minyan before Rosh Hashanah?

Tags: tefilla, selichot, elul

So my Hebrew isn't great and my ability to differentiate it from Aramaic is worse. I won't be able to do selichot with a minyan this year and am, to be frank, limited on time every day.  I'm trying to figure out which selichot sections to omit when davening alone. I know to skip the 13 middot and the Aramaic sections, but since I'll be reading mostly the English and transliterated sections, I need to know exactly which prayer sections these are. All I'm seeing on every website thus far, including this one, is advice to skip this, this, that, "etc". What's the "etc."? At the moment it's looking like I won't be able to complete this mitzvah this year because of both the long service and limited info for beginners.

Comment: If you're reciting in English I don't see why it would matter if it was translated from Aramaic

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!